# How to evaluate multiple records against a single record to find the absence of matching values?

Tags: sql, join, nested, relationship, where-clause

I'm creating some QA/QC queries to clean up my data and I am trying to find the absence of matching values between two tables. In total, I have three tables, Inspections (INSP), Risk Assessments (RA) and Work Orders (WO).  Inspections generate Risk Assessments (INSP.GlobalID = RA.InspectionGlobalID) and are 1 to many. Risk Assessments generate Work Orders and are many to 1 (RA.WorkOrderGlobalID = WO.GlobalID). Inspections and Work Orders are 1 to 1 (INSP.GlobalID = WO.InspectionGlobalID). They both have a "Priority" field which is a smallint , that ranges from 0-12 and indicates how important the work order is and when it gets done (12 being the most critical). The issue I'm having is that there can be multiple RA records associated to a single work order.   I'm trying to find instances where there is an absence of matching values between the Risk Assessment(s) Priority to the Work Order Priority. For example, there can be 3 RA's with Priorities 6, 8, 10.  The Work Order could have the 8 Priority (which is acceptable) and in this case I wouldn't want to select any of these RA's because there is a matching Priority in the group, but my query is selecting the 6 and 10 Priority RA's from the group.  How do I evaluate all RA's associated to a INSP and select records where there is no matching Priority at all between the two tables (RA/WO).

```
SELECT
RA.Priority,
WO.Priority , 
RA.InspectionGlobalID as RA_INSP_GLBID,
WO.InspectionGlobalID,
RA.WorkOrderGlobalID as RAWOGLBID,
WO.GlobalID,
WO.OBJECTID as WOID, 
INSP.GlobalID,
INSP.OBJECTID as INID,
RA.OBJECTID RA_OBJECTID

FROM 
CFAdmin.RISKASSESSMENT_EVW as RA INNER JOIN
CFAdmin.WORKORDER_EVW AS WO ON WO.GlobalID = RA.WorkOrderGlobalID LEFT OUTER JOIN
CFAdmin.INSPECTION_EVW as INSP ON INSP.GlobalID = RA.InspectionGlobalID LEFT OUTER JOIN
CFAdmin.PLANTINGSPACE_EVW as PS ON INSP.PlantingSpaceGlobalID = PS.GlobalID 

WHERE
RA.Priority <> WO.Priority AND          
INSP.InspectionDate IS NOT NULL AND             
(INSP.CreatedDate > '7/1/2018') AND             
WO.CancelDate IS NULL AND
WO.Status <>2 AND                               
(WO.CreatedDate > '7/1/2018') AND                            
WO.Type NOT IN (17,18, 44,45,3) AND            
WO.WOEntity = 0
```

Comment: I'm trying to find mismatches of the Priority field between the two tables...but my query is selecting the [mismatches].  Maybe don't understand your requirement.  If it's in the 4th sentence, your query is working correctly.  Or is last sentence of paragraph 1 saying that because the Priority 8 record matches, you don't want to see any records that are associated with that WO?  (not the 6, 8, or 10)  But if the WO in that case had Priority 7, you would want to see all of those records?

Comment: Hey dougp, I rephrased the question and hope that made it a little clearer.  Basically I'm trying to find records where there is a complete absence of a match between a group of RA's and a WO for the Priority field.

Comment: Rows in a table with no join match in another is a faq. In relational algebra it's ANTIJOIN. When columns are the same it's algebra DIFFERENCE, SQL EXCEPT. Not getting all rows from a left join is also a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS/product & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular base table initialization. PS When you get a result that you don't expect, postpone your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.

Comment: Apologies @philipxy, still finding my way on here.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boiling your SQL down to just the part that relates to this question:
(You're not even using anything from PLANTINGSPACE_EVW)

```
SELECT RA.Priority
, WO.Priority
, RA.WorkOrderGlobalID as RAWOGLBID
, WO.GlobalID

FROM CFAdmin.RISKASSESSMENT_EVW as RA
  INNER JOIN CFAdmin.WORKORDER_EVW AS WO ON WO.GlobalID = RA.WorkOrderGlobalID
                                        AND WO.Priority <> RA.Priority

WHERE WO.CancelDate IS NULL
  AND WO.Status <> 2
  AND WO.CreatedDate > cast('7/1/2018' as date)
  AND WO.Type NOT IN (17, 18, 44, 45, 3)
  AND WO.WOEntity = 0
```

You should get all of the records where the priorities don't match.

I can't test without sample data, but how about something like this?

```
SELECT RA.Priority
, WO.Priority
, RA.InspectionGlobalID as RA_INSP_GLBID
, WO.InspectionGlobalID
, RA.WorkOrderGlobalID as RAWOGLBID
, WO.GlobalID
, WO.OBJECTID as WOID
, RA.OBJECTID RA_OBJECTID

FROM CFAdmin.RISKASSESSMENT_EVW as RA
  INNER JOIN CFAdmin.WORKORDER_EVW AS WO ON WO.GlobalID = RA.WorkOrderGlobalID

WHERE WO.GlobalId not in (
    SELECT distinct WO2.GlobalID

    FROM CFAdmin.RISKASSESSMENT_EVW as RA2
      INNER JOIN CFAdmin.WORKORDER_EVW AS WO2 ON WO2.GlobalID = RA2.WorkOrderGlobalID
                                             AND WO2.Priority = RA2.Priority
  )
  AND WO.CancelDate IS NULL
  AND WO.Status <> 2
  AND (WO.CreatedDate > '7/1/2018')
  AND WO.Type NOT IN (17, 18, 44, 45, 3)
  AND WO.WOEntity = 0
```

Comment: Thanks @dougp this is exactly the result set I was looking for! learning about sub-queries  in the WHERE clause has been really useful.

Comment: @KurtCederholm & dougp It is generally better to use WHERE NOT EXISTS, because of how IN & NOT IN treat NULL--x NOT IN (...) is not NOT (x IN (...)); the following are all unknown/NULL: x IN ((NULL)), NULL IN ((x),...), x NOT IN ((NULL)) & NULL NOT IN ((x),...)). NOT EXISTS is also more concise than NOT IN when dealing with unmatched subrows with more than one column in SQLs that don't allow a row as left operand of NOT IN.

Comment: My method works.  Your comment is largely incomprehensible (probably because you can't really format a comment on this site), but I think what you are recommending (based on a quick reading of a simple example of EXISTS) is that a correlated subquery should be used.  I was excited about correlated subqueries when I first learned SQL.  What a cool way to write a query.  But I have found that they are difficult for the next person to support.  Now I use them only when absolutely necessary -- and I haven't found a need in over 10 years.